# Script Shell Extract substring

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script

Please, i'd like to extract string just before '.fr'.
Here is some lines of my file:

```
g-82.text.text1.fr.worker1
g-xx.yyyyyy.zzzz.fr.worker2
```

i'd like to extract this text:

```
g-82.text.text1
g-xx.yyyyyy.zzzz
```

Please, which command i have to use in my script shell ?
I work on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04.1 LTS distribution.

Thank you much.

Best Regards.

Comment: Which OS? Which shell?

Comment: Question edited. I work on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04.1 LTS distribution. Bests.

Comment: It's a bit late, because I had to go out, but it's worth pointing out that you can do it with variable expansion, along the lines of `for f in $(cat FileNames.txt); do echo ${f%.fr.*}; done`. If any of the files contain blanks, you will need to scan the file with a `while` loop instead, eg `while f=$(line); do echo ${f%.fr.*}; done <FileNames.txt`. Note that any file names _not_ containing `.fr.` will be output vertatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead regex:

```
echo "g-82.text.text1.fr.worker1" | grep -Po '.*(?=.fr)'
echo "g-xx.yyyyyy.zzzz.fr.worker2" | grep -Po '.*(?=.fr)'
```

Documentation here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: Thank you much for help :) Please, is it possible to do this variable="g-82.text.text1.fr.worker1" | grep -Po '.*(?=.fr)'

Comment: `VAR=$(echo "g-xx.yyyyyy.zzzz.fr.worker2" | grep -Po '.*(?=.fr)')`

Comment: Adjust that to `VAR="$(...)"` [add the double quotes] to be safe in situations where the string contains space(s).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sed` command.

```
sed 's/.fr.*//' file_name.txt
```

**Explanation:** `sed` will remove the part of the line matching the regular expression `.fr.*` from each line in the file, thus leaving the content before `.fr`.

`.fr.*` means `.fr.` followed by anything.

Comment: `echo 'villafranca' | sed 's/.fr.*//'`  --> `vill`

Answer (score 1):

Try
`cut -d'.' -f-3 <file_name.txt`

`-d` defines the "field delimiter",
Do put it inside '-quotes, so it is "safe from bash" (some characters has special meaning in bash, this is the means to avoid trouble)
Effect here -> split at `.` chars.

`-f` defines which "fields" to keep, => `-3` => Effect here: all from the beginning up to and including the third.

`man cut` - for more options.